# Is it possible to store a ngTemplate, and draw it from another componet?

Tags: angular

Using angular 9, A part from the reasons why I would like to to this, and I know there might be better implementation. I would like to know if it's possible to store a template, and render it somewhere else. Like a react like approach.

Ex :

componentA.html =>

```
<ng-template #templating>
  // template html
</ng-template>
```

componentA.ts =>

```
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template;
  //...
  ngAfterViewInit () => {
     refComponentB.template = template;
  }
```

componentB.html =>

```
<div>
  {{template}} // draw the template stored in componentA.
</div>
```

component A and component B are not related so no ngContent or things like this are available.

Comment: not sure if this gonna work, have you tried setting `innerHTML` somewhere? may be here `refComponentB.template`?

Comment: yes, but innerHTML looks like] it is  not working with not native DOM elements